# Difference between C# and VB.NET console session

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console-application

Ok, so I have [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9582933/610380) written in C++ that call the function `SetThreadDesktop`. I call this function from a dll when running as System user on Windows XP.

When called from a C# console application, the function succeeds, but when called from a VB.NET console application, it doesn't. With `GetLastError`, I saw that the error message was this:

```
SetThreadDesktop failed with error 170: The requested resource is in use (translated from french)
```

**How does it come that it works for a C# console app and not for a VB.NET one?** Btw, it doesn't work for a winform app neither. Can any .NET master explain this to me?
Is it a compiler option that I have to change?

Thanks

Comment: Need to see code. C# and vb do things differently.

Comment: @LachlanB The code does really nothing else than importing the dll and then call the function, in both C# and VB.NET

Comment: If the C# code works and the VB.NET does not then your VB.NET code is incorrect.  As to the reason it doesn't work for a Win32 form, without your code, We can't help you with that problem.

Comment: The VB.NET code enters in the function of the DLL, cause various things are done before the call of SetThreadDesktop, so I don't see how the VB.NET code could be incorrect...Maybe I should post it so you can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `<MTAThread>` attribute on your (VB) Main method as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/24/stathread-vs-mtathread-whorst.aspx).

That's really the only thing that differs between C# and VB Console projects by default.

Comment: And that is what solved my problem! Thanks :) But this trick doesn't work for Winform though

Comment: That's because winforms apps must be STAThread, otherwise they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you declare the extern function as `public shared`?

```
<DllImport("AltCtrlDelCpp.dll")> _
Public Shared Function SimulateAltControlDel() As Boolean
```

Comment: Yes - dll import has to be applied onto a shared/static method. Of course, if the method is declared within a module then `shared` is implied.