# How can I simulate ctrl alt del

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to generate a python script command line for the shortcut in ctrl alt del or go directly in "change a password", Or any executable file for that shortcut in windows 8.

I already refer to this question but its not working for me.
[.NET Simulate Ctrl+Alt+Del Sendkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047344/net-simulate-ctrlaltdel-sendkeys)

My target is create an app or way directly to change a password in windows 8 or ctrl alt del and then click change a password

Any suggestion/comments, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You want to change the users password using Python? Have a look at: http://superuser.com/a/456560/76028

Comment: @Kay good job answering the "Y" in this XY question :)

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because in my case, every users should change their domain password every day. As of now, in my application I am just using pop up message to notify them to change their password if they are not yet done within the day, so right now I decided to create an app or script to call which will direct them into change a password in win 8, because most of the users are not familiar with computer or just a beginners.

Answer (score 3):

As all of the answers on that question state, its very unlikely that you will be able to send this specific key combination. 
[<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is a privileged key combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete) in Windows, and I'd guess any rudimentary attempt to simulate it won't be acknowledged by Windows - for a good reason.

Most answers I've seen suggest you'll need to either use the `win32com` library or `ctypes` in Python. I won't link to them, but they are searchable using "python simulate crtl alt del".

In either case, you still need to run the app at elevated privileges which still negates the ease of use.

I'd strongly recommend that you don't do this.

Comment: "I'd strongly recommend that you don't do this" +1 just for this.