# PowerShell operating a ComObject remotely

Tags: powershell

I want to send the equivalent of ALT_CTRL_END to a remote computer using PowerShell:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {(New-Object -ComObject shell.application).WindowsSecurity()}
```

This fails to perform the action on the remote computer. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windowssecurity
Sends CTRL+ALT+DEL not CTRL+ALT+END and also

> This method can be used only when connected by a terminal session to Microsoft Terminal Server.

If you need CTRL+ALT+DEL then [.NET Simulate Ctrl+Alt+Del Sendkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047344/net-simulate-ctrlaltdel-sendkeys) should help.